# Undefined index in variable iteration when UPDATE to database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form which has 40 questions with radio button. In number 1, it's written like this :

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name="j1" value="A">A. Answer 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="j1" value="B">B. Answer 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="j1" value="C">C. Answer 3<br>
```

For number 2, the name is `j2`, number 3 as `j3`, etc.

After it, it will be send to database

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    for($i=1;$i<=40;$i++){
        ${"j".$i}=(htmlentities(strip_tags(trim($_POST["j{$i}"]))));
        if(empty(${"j".$i})){
            ${"j".$i}="X";
        }
    }
    $query="UPDATE answer SET ";
    for($i=1;$i<=40;$i++){
        $query.="j{$i}=${"j".$i}, ";
    }
    $query.="datesubmit='$datesubmit' WHERE email='$email'";

    $result=mysqli_query($link,$query);
    if($result){
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
    else{
        die("Query error, code : " .mysqli_errno($link). " - " .mysqli_error($link));
    }
}
```

It throws some error :

- When the question isn't answered, it throws

  > Undefined index: j3

(if the number 3 is empty), although i've assigned 'X' for the empty answer

- It also throws database error

  > Query error, code : 1054 - Unknown column 'A' in 'field list'

Any idea?

Comment: have you tried checking the parameters before looping it? and i think unanswered questions should have a default value so that the undefined index error will not occur

Comment: Add first in your loop : if(empty($_POST["j{$i}"]))  { ${"j".$i}="X"; continue; }